# AWS profile snippet

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to get the profile snippet (the few lines that go into ~/.aws/config) after login into AWS Management Console? In my case I can login into AWS Management Console and Switch Role but I don't have the lines that need to go into ~/.aws/config for the profile. So, the question is - how to get those lines from within the UI (AWS Management Console)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a way to retrieve these pre-populated from the AWS console.

Simply add some variant of the following to ~/.aws/config:

```
[profile1]
region = us-east-1
s3 =
    signature_version = s3v4
    use_accelerate_endpoint = false
```

and add some variant of the following to ~/.aws/credentials:

```
[profile1]
aws_access_key_id = key-here
aws_secret_access_key = secret-here
region = region-here
```

This assumes you're using IAM user credentials which you can download when you create the IAM user.

Rename `profile1` to `default`, if you want this to be your default profile.

Comment: Any idea how to make a request for this feature?

Comment: You might take a look at github tools for managing credentials (e.g. [benkehoe/aws-export-credentials](https://github.com/benkehoe/aws-export-credentials). You might also consider using the Feedback button in the AWS console (assuming you can find one on a login or IAM page somewhere). Twitter is another option that I've seen people use.